# How to add a dropdown icon in a header of a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table as follows.

In Cell I4, the header is `Row Labels`, and there is a dropdown icon on the right, which is good.

Now, I would like to add such a dropdown icon in Cell J4 where the header is `Age`, so that I could undertake filtering over Age. Does anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

**OPTION 1 - change the report layout**

Put your cursor in the pivot table.
Select Design>Report Layout>Show in Tabular Form

[image]

**OPTION 2 - filter the report in its existing layout**

You can filter the report using the drop-down on 'Row labels'. Like this:

[image]

Comment: "Show in Tabular Form" works for me. Thank you.